# Encryption/Decryption with SIP TLS

Tags: c#, encryption, sip, x509certificate2

In my SIP Sorcery project I'm creating a TLS connection to my remote server, with a certificate provider by the remote server.
The connection seems fine with following code snippet:

```
    static SIPTLSChannel channel_tls;
    static IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("1.2.3.4"), 5061);
    static IPEndPoint localEndPoint= new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.1"), 8080);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Certificate file path
        string Certificate = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Certificate\myCa.cer";

        // Load the certificate into an X509Certificate object.
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(Certificate);

        //TLS Channel connection
        channel_Tls = new SIPTLSChannel(cert, localEndPoint);
        Transport.RemoveSIPChannel(channel_Tcp);
        Transport.AddSIPChannel(channel_Tls);

        SIPRequest subscribe = new SIPRequest();
        .... [setting subscribe parameters] ....

        channel_Tls.Send(remoteEP, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(subscribe.ToString()), "myCa.cer");
    }
```

But I'm struggled on how do I create a Private key for en-/decryption of my data sent between client and server?? I can see that the cert.PublicKey isn't empty. I'm receiving some application data, but since I can't decrypt it without a private key, then I can't see what goes wrong between my client and server...

Comment: Are you encrypting independently of TLS?

Comment: @PeterRitchie As sipwiz pointing, the TLS wrapup in SIP Sorcery handle the encryption/decryption. So I guess my actual issue is how I get a matching privat/public key value pair.

Comment: If the TLS is doing the encryption/decryptions, what do you need the keys for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to create any additional encryption keys. The TLS connection will encrypt and decrypt any data sent on the connection. If you do a wireshark trace you will be able to see the TLS handshake after which all subsequent packets will essentially be random bytes.

In order for the SIP TLS channel to be able to operate the file or certificate store name you pass to it MUST have a private key included or accessible. From the looks of your sample if you are providing a .cer file then more than likely there is no private key available and the SIP TLS channel will fail to initialise. Typically you need a .pfx or equivalent file that couples the ceritifcate to use with the private key.

Also on the Send call you don't pass in a file ptah and instead you should be passing the name you will accept for the remote server certiicate. The SIP TLS channel will then match the certificate name provided by the remote server with the one you are prepared to accept.

```
channel_Tls.Send(remoteEP, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(subscribe.ToString()), "sip.someserver.com");
```

**Update**:

I was slightly mistaken in one of the comments below in that an exception will only be thrown if there is no private key available on the SIPTLSChannel WHEN a client attempts to connect. If you are only intending to use the SIPTLSChannel for outgoing connections then you don't need a private key (unless the server at the other end is authenticating you with the certificate which would be unusual in the SIP World).

As to your original question about getting the decrypted data out of the SIPTLSChannel it's as I mentioned originally and it all happens under the hood. Below is an example of establishing a connection to a SIP TLS server (in this case sipsorcery.com) and reading the response. Both the transmitted request and response from the server are carried over an encrypted TLS channel which you can verify by using wireshark.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SIPSorcery.Net;
using SIPSorcery.SIP;
using SIPSorcery.SIP.App;
using SIPSorcery.Sys;

namespace SIPTLS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var sipTransport = new SIPTransport(SIPDNSManager.ResolveSIPService, new SIPTransactionEngine());
                sipTransport.SIPTransportRequestReceived += SIPRequestReceived;
                sipTransport.SIPTransportResponseReceived += SIPResponseReceived;

                X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("test-cert.cer");
                SIPTLSChannel tlsChannel = new SIPTLSChannel(cert, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5061));
                sipTransport.AddSIPChannel(tlsChannel);

                var optionsReq = sipTransport.GetRequest(SIPMethodsEnum.OPTIONS, SIPURI.ParseSIPURI("sips:67.222.131.147:5061"));
                sipTransport.SendRequest(optionsReq);
            }
            catch(Exception excp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception Main. " + excp);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                Console.Read();
            }
        }

        private static void SIPRequestReceived(SIPEndPoint localSIPEndPoint, SIPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, SIPRequest sipRequest)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SIP request received from " + remoteEndPoint + ".");
            Console.WriteLine(sipRequest.ToString());
        }

        private static void SIPResponseReceived(SIPEndPoint localSIPEndPoint, SIPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, SIPResponse sipResponse)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SIP response received from " + remoteEndPoint + ".");
            Console.WriteLine(sipResponse.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to generate your own certificates and private keys this page on setting up [MySQL certificates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-ssl-certs.html) is a good guide.

You can test whether your certificate has a private key available for client connections by using a browser to connect to the socket the TLS channel is using, e.g. in the above samples's case I use https://myipaddress.com:5061.

Comment: So the string parameter in the send method is dns of the remote server, or is it a name located in the .cer file??
How do I obtain the .pfx or equvalent key file?? Havn't really used priv/pub keys in my system yet. I have a .cer file on my computer, and have installed it on my computer, so its figuring in the Certificate Manager of windows. I can see the Handshake session in WS, and I see that after the negotiation, I'm sending an app data which is encrypted, but then notthing happens, probably be cause I'm sending something wrong to the server. But I can't derypt the app data without a key.

Comment: The Send method string parameter needs to be the Common Name of the TLS certificate provided by the server. The sipsorcery TLS channel shouldn't even be initialising without a private key so I guess you must have one. Where are you expecting to decrypt data? You can't do it manually, the TLS decryption all happens under the hood in the .Net encrypted stream.

Comment: I was hoping that I could export the key, to decrypt the data traced in Wireshark, but thats only for debuging. I'm supposed to use decrypting inside my sip application (SIPResponseReceived event), and pass signaling forth and back between server and client. If I do a cert.PrivateKey of the code snippet, it return null. Are there any way to check if this PK is initialsed? If I look into my mmc.exe, there isn't bound any key to the certificate imported yet, and I'm unsure if it's me who should fabricate a PK and/or Public key, or something the server should be providing to me?

Comment: You can open the .cer file in notepad and see if there's a private key included. The file should be base64 encoded and have two distinct sections, one for the certificate and one for the private key. In addition to that openssl is the best tool for working with certificates and private keys. How did you generate the certificate in the myCa.cer file?

Comment: The .cer file only have a BEGIN and END Certificate inside. It is tho encoded as base64. The .cer file is generated from my server provider.

Comment: Definitely no private key then. Are you sure there are no exception messages being generated when you create the SIPTLSChannel? Do you have a log4net section in your app.config so that you can get the log messages from the sipsorcery libraries?

Comment: I'll try to get it running with log4net and trace if there is any exception thrown tomorrow. But the funny thing is, that the handshake initiation seems to be fine, so my guess is that it doesn't throw any exceptions in the initialization of SIPTLSChannel.

Comment: I have now cleaned my solution, and added log4net support for log tracking (didn't know it was so easy to use btw, thought it need an apache server etc. DOH!). The TLSChannel doesn't give any errors. Here is a paste of my logging http://pastebin.com/3NF3PZvf and after the last msg, notthing happens.

Comment: Btw, if I go to the .cer files properties, and click on the details tab, I can see the Public key listed. Is that for any use? As I wrtoe I can't see anything but the begin / end certificate when I open it in np++.

Comment: An updated pastebin due to some old testing crap in the previous link http://pastebin.com/g5uJ1x45 @Comment 8

Comment: Thanks. I saw that a priv key wasn't needed, and receiving data from my server now. I still havn't figured if there is any way to export a key file, that I can use for Wireshark tracing decrypting, but at least I can now catch events thrown back to me from the server.